# Send message from bot to self with telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I'm trying to send a message to myself using a Telegram bot I have created, and I got the values from https://my.telegram.org as well as the BotFather.

```py
import telebot
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient


def telegram_setup():
    api_id = 12345678
    api_hash = 'X'
    token = 'X'
    phone = '+111'
    client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone)
        client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    return client


def send_message(client, message):
    try:
        entity = client.get_entity('username')
        client.send_message(entity, message, parse_mode='html')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    client.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = telegram_setup()
    message = "test"
    send_message(client, message)
```

The first time I ran this, it sent me a message asking for a code which I supplied. Running it again caused "test" to appear under "Saved Messages" in Telegram, rather than coming from my bot.

Any idea what's causing this or how to resolve it?

Thanks.

EDIT: I realised I'm not using `token` anywhere, but I'm not sure where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The bot token is required in client.start() as `bot_token` (`bot_token`=`"token"`), if what you do is a bot, your phone is not needed.

**Edit:** You made a userbot, not a bot.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The userbot uses your Telegram account, sends messages as if it were you.

Comment: How do I modify my code to send it as the bot then?

Comment: I'm not trying to program a bot, I'm just trying to programmatically send myself a message (from my bot). But the Saved Messages thing doesn't work as it doesn't give me a notification

Comment: only if telethon had a documentation explaining how to sign in. oh wait, there is one docs.telethon.dev `client.start(bot_token=token)`

Comment: To "send the message to yourself" you would use a `userbot` (this has nothing to do with `@BotFather`), if you want it to notify you should start the client with a `bot_token` (so you would send the message from the bot, to your user).